# Can't figure out how to use schedule and tidy resource in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have puppet code, that I can't manage to get to work:

```
schedule { 'daily_once':
        period => daily,
        repeat => 1,
}
node 'puppet1' {
        tidy { '/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/bucket':
                age => '5w',
                recurse => true,
                rmdirs => true,
                backup => false,
                schedule => 'daily_once',
        }
        tidy { '/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/reports':
                age => '5w',
                recurse => true,
                rmdirs => true,
                backup => false,
                schedule => 'daily_once',
        }
}
```

tidy resource still keep gets executed every time puppet agent runs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [long outstanding bug](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6020) in Puppet, first reported for Puppet 2.6.4

As far as I know, there is currently no known solution.